# How to add path variable in HttpGet request

Tags: java, spring, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I was using Spring where I can get the path variable of client directly as follows:

```
@Override
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{username}/projects", method = GET)
public void projects(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("username") String username, 
@RequestParam(value="position", required=false) Integer position) {

  System.out.println("Got username: "+username);
}
```

Now I want to get the same path variable value using apache `HttpClient` as follows:

```
String projectsUrl = base_url + "userApi/users/{username}/projects?position="+position;
HttpGet getProjects = new HttpGet(projectsUrl);
```

Obviously this will not work because path variable `username` is missing. So how to get this `username` using HttpClient?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question - but you can use `org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplate` to `expand` your template. I.e. replacing `{username}` with an actual value

Comment: `UriComponentsBuilder` could be of use to build the URL - like this: `UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(baseUrl).path("/api/users/{username}").queryParam("page", page).buildAndExpand(username).encode().toString()`